Getting Error During Creating SessionEntityType in Dailogflow CX
I am currently working on implementing session entities to store custom values during the current session in Google Dialogflow CX. However, I encountered an error:

Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: com.google.apps.framework.request.NotFoundException: No entity is found for this agent id '844d799-4bc6-826b-bfc38de06

and entity id 'userState'`. My objective is to persist the value associated with the key ‘userState’ across sessions. I am utilizing the Node.js client for this purpose.
async createContextSessionEntities(conversationId: string, entityTypeDisplayName: string, contextParameters: string[], environment?: string, userId?: string, entityMode?: string) {
    // console.log(conversationId,entityTypeDisplayName, contextParameters, entityMode);
    try {
        const sessionEntityTypesClient = new dialogflow.SessionEntityTypesClient(
            {
                credentials: this.config as any,
                apiEndpoint: this.location !== 'global' ? `${this.location}-dialogflow.googleapis.com` : 'dialogflow.googleapis.com'
            });
        

        const sessionEntityTypesClientPath = sessionEntityTypesClient.projectLocationAgentSessionPath(
            this.dialogFlowProjectId,
            this.location,
            this.agentid,
            conversationId
        )
        const sessionParamter = {
            name: `${sessionEntityTypesClientPath}/entityTypes/${entityTypeDisplayName}`,
            entityOverrideMode: entityMode || "ENTITY_OVERRIDE_MODE_SUPPLEMENT" as any,
            entities: [{
                name: Object.keys(contextParameters) as any,
                value: Object.keys(contextParameters) as any,
              }]}
        
        const sessionEntityTypeRequest = {
            parent: sessionEntityTypesClientPath,
            sessionEntityType: sessionParamter,
        };
        const [response] = await sessionEntityTypesClient.createSessionEntityType(
            sessionEntityTypeRequest
        );
        LogManager.EventInfoLog('SessionEntityType created:');
        
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        LogManager.EventErrorLog('df error creating session entity', error.stack)
        throw new Error(error.stack);
    }
}

In the context of my code, the variable entityTypeDisplayName corresponds to the value ‘userState’.

Hi @subhajit saha, Did you check and follow this documentation to create the session entity ? Let me know if this helped you or not.

Hi @DhirajSingh, this document is for dialogflow es. between the same way i tried. but not worked for me

It appears that this issue has to be investigated further, so if you have a support plan please create a new GCP support case. Otherwise, you can open a new issue on the issue tracker describing your issue.
